# need string name, why showing integer Value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, textbox, dataset

when i will press gno then it will show me gname. but presently it is showing me an money amonut what is the problem

```
  protected void txtgno_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CompanybookConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblNewgroup WHERE gno=@gno", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gno", txtgno.Text);
                using (con)
                {
                    con.Open();
                    Object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (result != null)
                        //   lblResult.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", result); 
                        txtgname.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", result);


                    // else
                    //   lblResult.Text = "No match!"; 
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is schema design of your table ` tblNewgroup`? I if the first column is `gno`, thats why it is display `gno` value.

Comment: string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); might help you

Comment: it does not show anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the column name you want to return in your SQL query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT gname FROM tblNewgroup WHERE gno=@gno", con);
```

Comment: changed but not working.

Comment: @user3064392 What's the value of `result` in the debugger?